# Record a html5 page as a video

Tags: python, linux, shell, ffmpeg, phantomjs

My goal is to have a Ubuntu (Desktop) server that "simply" converts html5 webpages into videos. I want to capture the smooth css and js-animations.

So far I've tried this: (phantomjs)
https://gist.github.com/phanan/e03f75082e6eb114a35c

The timing and framerate is either choppy or to fast.

My best solution so far is to open up a Google Chrome window in kiosk mode, wait 3 seconds and then record via ffmpeg with x11grab. It feels like a "bloaty" and unprofessional solution.

**program.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
duration=$1
outputFile=$2
stop=$(($duration+5))

./openBrowser.sh $stop & PIDOIS=$!
./recScreen.sh $duration $outputFile & PIDMIX=$!
wait $PIDIOS
wait $PIDMIX
```

**recScreen.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset ultrafast -t "$1" "$2".mkv
killall -9 chrome
```

**openBrowser.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/google-chrome --kiosk --incognito http://localhost/testanimation
```

Can this be done in a different way? Perhaps a virtual display? (must have GPU though). This should be as a desktop server so I don't want popups or any fail messages from the OS (as it would be burned into the video...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ?

```
recordmydesktop
```

It can create a video from a single window from the command line.
I used

```
recordmydesktop --windowid $(xwininfo | awk '/Window id:/ {print $4}') --no-cursor --delay 1S --device default --channels 2 --fps 50 --freq 22050 --v_quality 53 --s_quality 5 -o $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
```

to record a video of my browser, (this is interactive, but your script can detect windowid.)

Comment: I found `--on-the-fly-encoding` was choppy